# vertical Menu Ant design height 100%

Tags: javascript, html, antd

Good afternoon. I'm new to web development and I'm not able to put the ant design menu (https://ant.design/components/menu/) at 100% of the screen height.

I tried to put `<Layout style = {{height:" 100vh "}}>` before the  but it did not work.

Here's the code I'm using

.
.
.
.
.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Layout, Menu, Breadcrumb, Icon, Button } from 'antd';

const { Header, Content, Footer, Sider } = Layout;
const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu;

export class SideMenu extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {collapsed: false}
  }

  toggleCollapsed (){
     this.setState({
       collapsed: !this.state.collapsed
     })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: 256 }}>
        <Menu
          defaultSelectedKeys={[]}
          defaultOpenKeys={[]}
          mode="inline"
          theme="light"
          inlineCollapsed={this.state.collapsed}
        >
          <Menu.Item key="0">
            <div onClick={this.toggleCollapsed.bind(this)}>
              <Icon type={this.state.collapsed ? 'menu-unfold' : 'menufold'}/>
            </div>
          </Menu.Item>    
          ...    
          <Menu.Item key="5">
            <Icon type="rocket" />
            <span>Funções</span>
          </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to manage separate style sheet(in my case menu.less)  and put it this code

it should be work

```
.menu-style {

height: 100vh;
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
}
```

just try it.

Comment: worked perfectly. I just added the tag by id.

#full {
  height: 100vh;
}

Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelFernandes if someone provides the answer which helped you, please mark it as correct and add a point :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ref` get the DOM you wanted reference height. Then use the height at some Components.

```
function refIt(theDOM) {
  const height = theDOM.clientHeight;
  this.setState({ height });
}

return (<div ref={theDOM => refIt(theDOM)}>
  <div height={this.state.height}>
  </div>
</div>);
```